# Query site collection property bag in SPFx extension

Tags: sharepoint-rest-api, spfx, site-collection, spfx-extensions, pnpjs

I am building an SPFx Application Customizer for a Powell365 project, and trying to have it use custom properties from the current site collections's property bag.

I already managed to get these properties in SP PowerShell, using the code linked below. 
How can I access those values in my SPFx Applicaton Customizer, and what are the modules I need to import?

The code from [PnP JS - SP Webs](https://pnp.github.io/pnpjs/sp/docs/webs/) throws a Type error:

> "Object does not support the property or method "from".

Any support will be appreciated! Please let me know if I can supply more information.

[Get complex properties](https://pnp.github.io/pnpjs/sp/docs/webs/#get-complex-properties):

```
import { sp } from "@pnp/sp";
sp.web.select("AllProperties").expand("AllProperties").get().then(success=>{[...]},error=>
{[...]})
```

PowerShell Script: [SharePoint Online: Get-Set Property Bag Values with PowerShell](https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2018/03/sharepoint-online-get-set-property-bag-values-using-powershell.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you are using this in Internet Explorer.

You need to use a polyfill to use this in IE 11.

You can download the package using `npm install --save @pnp/polyfill-ie11` command.

After that, you can import it in your code as below:

```
import "@pnp/polyfill-ie11";
import { sp } from "@pnp/sp";
sp.web.select("AllProperties").expand("AllProperties").get().then(success=>{[...]},error=>
{[...]})
```

Reference - [PnPJS polyfills](https://pnp.github.io/pnpjs/documentation/polyfill/)

Comment: Thank you, @gautam-sheth, this works just as desired.

Comment: Welcome, you can [accept it as answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) by ticking the checkbox ! Cheers